# One MySql query to filter results by tags and return list of all tags used by results

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to combine two mysql queries into a single one.  The first query returns results based on multiple selected tags.  The second query returns a list of tags used in the database, ordered by their total count.

I have three tables, lets call them: 
 - 'LIB' (contains all images, data, ect.) 
 - 'TAGS' (contains all possible tags and their tag ids)
 - 'LIBTAGS' (contains records of all tags used in the lib, with LIB ids and TAG ids)

Example Tables:

```
LIB
---------------
id     -  12345
desc   -  'A description'
file   -  'example.jpg'
thumb  -  'exampleThumb.jpg'

TAGS
---------------
id   -   3500
tag  -   'exampletag'

LIBTAGS
--------------
libid  -  12345
tagid  -  3500
```

The first query looks like this:

```
SELECT from LIB l
JOIN LIBTAGS lt ON l.id = lt.libid
JOIN TAGS t ON lt.tagid = t.id
WHERE t.tag IN ('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3')  //varies with number of tags
GROUP BY l.id
HAVING count(DISTINCT t.tag) = 3 //varies with number of tags
```

This returns results from LIB containing all of the searched tags.

The second query looks like this:

```
SELECT lt.tagid, t.*, count(lt.tagid) AS cnt FROM LIBTAGS lt 
JOIN TAGS t ON lt.tagid = t.id 
GROUP BY lt.tagid 
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

This returns a list of the most used tags ordered by their total count.

My goal is to combine these and to return a list of tags (like above) but only for the results of the first query.  Can this be done?

The purpose of this is to allow users to narrow their results by tags, and then present them with a list of tags which they can further narrow it down by.

The output I'm looking for is the ability to loop through results for the first query (from LIB), and an array of tags (or list I can make into an array) from the second query.

Any insight or advice is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: SELECT * FROM (first query) x JOIN (second query) ON y.tagid = x.tagid ?

Comment: What is the relationship between all three tables? If possible update your question with a sample Database table structure for clarity. Nonetheless, using JOIN, you can get this working as expected.

Comment: @OmniPotens Adding example tables into the question.  Basically, the relationship is that the LIBTAGS table is connected to the primary keys of the other two.  'libid' would refer to the id of the item in the LIB table, 'tagid' refers to the id of the tag.  Apologies, my grasp of the lingo is not the best.

Comment: can you please show us desired output?

Comment: Have you tried using your 1st query into your 2nd query _FROM_ instead of _LIBTAGS lt_ ?

Comment: @Peter, I'm not exactly sure how to show it.  Perhaps there is a flaw in my thinking.  I'd like to loop through the results to output the results from the first query, and similarly for the second query.  However, they would have a very different number of returned records (far more LIB items than TAGS).  Is this better handled with two separate queries?

Comment: @KaiserM11, I don't completely understand the question, but I doubt I have tried that.  Would you be able to refer to an example of a query like this and I will give it a try?

Comment: Have a look here [link](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-subquery). Scroll down to **MySQL subquery in FROM clause**

Comment: @user1783964 there is nothing wrong with two separates queries. if you really want to have one query and one loop you can use `UNION`